# Winsock: strange conflict with SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

I have faced with a strange behavior.

The [manual claimed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "When two sockets are bound to the same port number but on different explicit interfaces, there is no conflict". **Why** the system fails in the following case on the step 3? Is it a bug in the OS?  (my post on [Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wsk/thread/2a342e09-1b48-4606-9154-92bcef052c83) has no answer)
**Is** there some workaround on this?

- Step 1. process A binds the 127.0.1.1:88 (default) — OK
- Step 2. process B binds the 127.0.0.1:88 (with SO_REUSEADDR) — OK
- Step 3. process C binds the 127.0.0.1:88 (with SO_REUSEADDR) — fail (10013 WSAEACCES)

Note: the tcp-ports are the same, the **interfaces are different** and explicit (between step 1 and 2-3). User is the same.

The problem occurs in the Windows Vista (32-bit), Windows Server 2008 (32-bit), Window Server 2008 R2 (64-bit), etc.

In Windows XP it is all right: step 3 succeeds.

**Update**: just for reference, the same problem: [Windows 7 socket bind behavior difference from XP, with reuse address socket option (WSAEACCES 10013 error)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/e8c72373-80c9-4a47-9d82-feefde0c66f6/windows-7-socket-bind-behavior-difference-from-xp-with-reuse-address-socket-option-wsaeacces-10013)

Comment: You have to use SO_REUSEADDR on all three binds. However binding two sockets to the same explicit interface and port when both sockets use SO_REUSEADDR is guaranteed to work *indeterminately.* Why are you doing this?

Comment: According documentation, this case should work successfully (without SO_REUSEADDR on the first step).

Comment: Why am I doing so? I have a web-application at back-end and Nginx at front-end. This web-application listen on 127.x.x.x:80 and Nginx listen on public:80. And Nginx has trouble on reload configuration. Workaround: using another port in back-end; but it is convenient to use port 80 for HTTP everywhere.

Comment: FWIW, a lot of the information on that link is incorrect (unfortunately that seems to be the case with a lot of MSDN docs), so it can't really be considered a reliable manual.

Comment: Does the machine actually have interfaces with IPs 127.0.1.1 and 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes, of course it has interface 127.0.0.1. See step 1 above. Please, try the experiment yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

Binding two sockets to the same explicit interface and port when both sockets use `SO_REUSEADDR` is guaranteed to succeed, even the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621.aspx) says so.  It has to be a bug in your code, either you are not enabling `SO_REUSEADDR` on both sockets prior to calling `bind()`, or you are not actually binding both sockets to the same explicit interface and port.

`bind()` does not return `WSAEACCES` if the interface/port are already in use.  It returns `WSAEADDRINUSE` instead.  `WSAEACCES` means you tried to bind to something that you do not have permission to bind to.  That is a different kind of error condition.

Comment: The same code works in Windows XP and fails in Windows Vista; I can't find a bug in my code. Could you please try this experiment by yourself?

Comment: I can reproduce the `WSAEACCES` on Windows 7 64bit. The problem is in the binding of A. When I remove that, binding B and C succeed as expected. Microsoft's docs say that should only happen if A is running under a different user account than B and C.  But I can get `WSAEACCES` to occur under the same account (even the same process), which contradicts the docs. `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` is not being used on any of the sockets, and no wildcard addresses are in use.

Comment: According to the docs, if A is in a different user account than B/C, "Enhanced Socket Security" comes into play on Windows 2003+, so A must enable `SO_REUSEADDR` as well or else B/C will fail. But ESS isn't supposed to come into play when the same user account is used, but apparently it does. If I have A enable `SO_REUSEADDR`, then both B and C succeed, but if A does not then B succeeds (but should fail under ESS) but C always fails.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation. I think A may not enable SO_REUSEADDR because of different interface. By the way, if C fails, why B is not fail at first (I mean, if the conflict occurs between A and B/C)?

Comment: I don't know why B succeeds but C fails. It also don't know why A would even be a factor when A, B, and C are all in the same user account (or even the same process), but it is. Microsoft must have really screwed something up when they re-write the WinSock stack in Vista, but this is not common usage of sockets, so most people probably never notice it.